# Get Sharepoint data list in php

Tags: php, apache, sharepoint

I tried to get SharePoint list in php. Below is code

```
require_once __DIR__ . '\Faker-master\src\autoload.php';  //Faker library       (https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)

require_once 'lib/SPOClient.php';



$username = 'aaaa.aaa@microsoft.com';
$password = '*******';
$url = "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com";



generateContacts($url,$username,$password);


function generateContacts($url,$username,$password){



$client = new SPOClient($url);

$client->signIn($username,$password);



$list = $client->getList('ClientMaster');

$contactsCount = 120;

for($i = 0; $i < $contactsCount; $i++){

     $contactEntry = createContactEntry();    

     $item = $list->addItem($contactEntry);

     print "Contact '{$item->Title}' has been created succesfully.\r\n";

  }
```

}

O/p:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid STS request. ' in E:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\ep\lib\SPOClient.php:260 Stack trace: #0 E:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\ep\lib\SPOClient.php(242): SPOClient->processToken('requestToken('ssss.kkkk...', '*****') #2 E:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\ep\listexamples.php(24): SPOClient->signIn('ssss.kkkk...', '******') #3 E:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\ep\listexamples.php(15): generateContacts('https://worldem...', 'sssss.kkk...', '******') #4 {main} thrown in E:\Apps\xampp\htdocs\ep\lib\SPOClient.php on line 260